# Ubuntu will not boot after updating to 15.05

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm an Ubuntu beginner.  I had been using 14.04LTS for several months because it had been promoted as a no-cost alternative to upgrading to a version of Windows from XP. During that time, all my personal files, including my T-bird emails were stored on Ubuntu.

Recently during an update, Ubuntu suggested that I may want to upgrade to 15.05, which I did.  Immediately after that, I tried to re-boot into Ubuntu, only to find:
"Kernal Panic - not syncing:  attempted to kill init!  exitcode = 0x0007f00"
and the computer quit responding.

I got as far as booting off of a Live CD, and trying the "Grub-repair", but it didn't work.  I got the same error screen.

I'm afraid that if I re-install Ubuntu it will over-write all my stored data, documents, emails, etc.

Please help me.  This Ubuntu/Linux thing is proving to be too complicated for someone who tried to follow the suggestions from Ubuntu.  If I can't get this fixed, I'll be forced to abandon Ubuntu and get a new version of Windows.

### My boot screen can be found at http://paste.ubuntu.com/12875715.

Re: version of Ubuntu:  Sorry, it may have been one of the versions mentioned.  I didn't catch the exact version.

I did enter the terminal command and here's what I got:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dbus-launch nautilus

(nautilus:6577): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

(nautilus:6577): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 271 was not found when attempting to remove it

(nautilus:6577): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 272 was not found when attempting to remove it

(nautilus:6577): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 273 was not found when attempting to remove it
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dbus-launch nautilus

(nautilus:6659): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Any ideas?  Do I just reinstall GRUB and keep my fingers crossed?

Comment: Maybe cuz 15.05 does not exist ;-) You meant 15.04? Or 15.10? >:)

Answer (score 0):

Besides that I never received a recommendation to upgrade an Ubuntu LTS version
to a "normal version" you can do the following to achieve at least what you want.

Boot from Ubuntu install media and save your personal data from within there.
The easiest way is using Nautilus file manager with root privileges - so do this :

Open a terminal and execute

```
sudo dbus-launch nautilus
```

Copy all the files and folders you want to keep to another internal partition or external drive.

Reinstall GRUB boot loader

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda5` = system partition | (taken from the pastebin output you provided)

To re-check the partition numbers use **GParted**, the tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.

If this does not work you can download a current Ubuntu version, install it and restore back the files and folders you saved before. Ubuntu 15.10 is just around the corner, so ... maybe wait ... ?